# how to achieve the following result using dict comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

Hello I would like to get all the 'Integer' values from a dict:

```
array_test = [{ "result1" : "date1",  "type" : "Integer"},{ "result1" : "date2", "type" : "null"}]
```

I tried:

```
test = {'result1':array_test['result1'] for element in array_test if array_test['type'] == "Integer"}
```

However I got this error:

```
>>> test = {'result1':array_test['result1'] for element in array_test if array_test['type'] == "Integer"}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
>>> 
>>>
```

So I would like to appreciate support to achieve the following output

```
test = [{ "result1" : "date1",  "type" : "Integer"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a list-comprehension, not dictionary-comprehension:

```
array_test = [{ "result1" : "date1",  "type" : "Integer"},{ "result1" : "date2", "type" : "null"}]

test = [x for x in array_test if x['type'] == 'Integer']
# [{'result1': 'date1', 'type': 'Integer'}]
```

*Why?* Because required output is a list (list of dictionaries).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support